# How to set up shading nodes for multiple objects that have a random color but specific colors need different settings

Tags: shaders, color, color-management, shader-nodes

I am kind of new to Blender and have been looking for this a few days now and can't seem to find out so I ended up here.

I have a base object on which I have scattered stars. For the coloring of the stars I have set up the following nodes to give it random coloring:

- Object info (Random) --> Colorramp (I have set up my colors) --> Principled BSDF (Base Color) --> Material Output.

Now I want to add metallic colors and these have a different roughness than my normal colors. So I tried to add in a new *ColorRamp* node with my metallic colors and a new *Principled BSDF* with a lower roughness setting followed by a *Mix Shader* to add in both BSDFs.

But the outcome gives me random roughness on all colors. I only want the specific colors to look metallic...

Comment: Hello :). Instead of randomizing colors, you could randomly assign different Principled Shaders

Comment: So you want to control the roughness like *if random color is metallic then 0.1 else 0.5*? What defines a color as metallic? And what do you use as *Fac* for the Mix Shader?

Comment: Yes i would like to control the roughness and metallic settings for specific colors. Lets say red and blue needs to be metallic 0 and roughness 0.5, gold and silver needs to be metallic 1 and roughness 0.2. 
I did not put a node into the Fac for the Mix shader tho..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need is a pair of data: the color and the info if it's a metal. When you use the *Object Info*'s *Random* value and a *ColorRamp* to define the colors of the stars then you can use another *ColorRamp* with black and white values to define if the color is a metal or not.

With this info, you can decide which value is used for *Roughness* (or the value for any other slot). A *MixRGB* node works as a switch to define the *Roughness* value.

In the example, the yellow and the white colors become the metals gold and silver. Their corresponding color range in the second *ColorRamp* node is set to white while it's black for all other colors. Their roughness is set to 0.5 for non-metal colors and 0.02 for metal colors.

[image: shader setup]

Comment: This is what I had been looking for. Thanks a lot for your time I really appreciate it, now i'm gonna take some time to try and understand the set up.